# Using Twitter API

Tags: twitter

Is there any good link to follow or an example to use Twitter API in C# .net application

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

i currently use [tweetsharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) 
 as i think its a good client

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice examples on this site:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2008/11/15/twitter-api-from-c-getting-a-user-s-time-line.aspx

The above example shows you how to get a users timeline.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/).  It's worked like a charm on many projects.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/05/ngtweet-silverlight-client-for-tweeter.html) is an example showing how to connect to Twitter using TweetSharp.